# Uncaught Error: No method named "toggle" in bootstrap bundle.js when i build dist in angular 4

Tags: angular

```
polyfills.632b34744581a0c4f58a.bundle.js:1 Uncaught Error: No method named "toggle" at HTMLUListElement. (scripts.9f3b3f8b796cac39acc9.bundle.js:1) at Function.each (scripts.9f3b3f8b796cac39acc9.bundle.js:1) at m.fn.init.each (scripts.9f3b3f8b796cac39acc9.bundle.js:1) at m.fn.init.e._jQueryInterface [as collapse] (scripts.9f3b3f8b796cac39acc9.bundle.js:1) at HTMLUListElement. (scripts.9f3b3f8b796cac39acc9.bundle.js:1) at Function.each (scripts.9f3b3f8b796cac39acc9.bundle.js:1) at m.fn.init.each (scripts.9f3b3f8b796cac39acc9.bundle.js:1) at HTMLAnchorElement. (scripts.9f3b3f8b796cac39acc9.bundle.js:1) at HTMLDocument.dispatch (scripts.9f3b3f8b796cac39acc9.bundle.js:1) at HTMLDocument.v.handle (scripts.9f3b3f8b796cac39acc9.bundle.js:1)
```

Comment: maybe show some code? how did you add bootstrap and the bootstrap js? via a cdn in your index.html or via npm? What bundler do you use? angular-cli? ...

Comment: <pre>bootstrap bundle</pre> via nmp build

Comment: I have seen the same thing.  Using Angular 5.1 and Angular CLI with AOT compilation.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with `@angular/cli: 1.6.5`

After upgrading to `@angular/cli: 1.7.3`, the error went away.

To upgrade CLI globally, do:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

To upgrade it locally, do:

```
npm install @angular/cli --save
```